# Format data in the UpdatePanel before save

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, webforms

I'm using an UpdatePanel in ASP.NEt WebForms to upload a image. I want to save the filename in the database, but NOT the path. I'm using following code

```
 <asp:TemplateField FooterText="Image 1" HeaderText="Image 1">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Image ID="Image11" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("pic") %>' Height="50px" onerror="this.style.display='none'" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatPanelImg1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
          <Triggers>
             <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="uploadbutton" />
          </Triggers>
          <ContentTemplate>
             <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
             <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Add image" OnClick="UploadbuttonClick" />
             <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("pic") %>' onerror="this.style.display='none'" /> 
          </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
      </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

And in the UploadbuttonClick method, I set the path to the image width `Image1.ImageUrl = virtualFilePath;` where `virtualFilePath` is the full virtual path to the file. When the data is saved, the database contains the full path to the file, but I only whant the file name.

**Edit 1:**
The code for UploadbuttonClick:

```
    protected void UploadbuttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (Button)sender;
        var fileUpload = (FileUpload)button.Parent.FindControl("FileUpload1");
        var imageViewer = (Image)button.Parent.FindControl("Image1");

        if (fileUpload.HasFile)
        {
            string fileName = fileUpload.FileName;
            fileName = RemoveInvalidChars(fileName);
            const string virtualPath = @"/images/news/";
            string serverPath = Server.MapPath(virtualPath);
            string serverFilePath = Path.Combine(serverPath, fileName);
            string virtualFilePath = Path.Combine(virtualPath, fileName);

            fileUpload.SaveAs(serverFilePath);

            imageViewer.ImageUrl = virtualFilePath;
        }
    }
```

**Edit 2:**
Code to save to the database

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
  ID="SqlDataSourceNews" 
  runat="server" 
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:connectionString %>" 
  UpdateCommand="UPDATE [foo] SET [pic] = @pic WHERE [id] = @id">
   <UpdateParameters>
      <asp:Parameter Name="pic" Type="String" />
   </UpdateParameters>
   <InsertParameters>
      <asp:Parameter Name="pic" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: The UploadbuttonClick use the FileUpload1.FileName to get the filename. I update my question to show the code

Comment: But which is your problem, you said "I want to save the filename in the database, but NOT the path." You already know how to get the Filename ( FileUpload1.FileName). Where are you saving the path in your DataBase?

Comment: virtualFilePath are /images/news/imagename.jpg, but I only whant to store imagename.jpg in the database.

Comment: @magol: are you mixing up database and file-system? [FileUpload.SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas.aspx) saves the file on the webserver and not in dbms.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter  I was thinking the same,  and i dont see a relation between the subject of this question "Format data in the UpdatePanel before save" against the "I want to save the filename in the database, but NOT the path. ". Still dont understand your question @magol sorry :(

Comment: The image is saved in the filesystem at /images/news/imagename.jpg. And in the database I seve the filename so that I now wich file to use. Maybe I was using a slightly misleading title. But what I want is that file is shown in Image1 after the image has been uploaded  to /images/news, but just the file name to be saved in the database

Comment: @magol: Ok, but where is the code where you are trying to save the FileName to database and what problems you have?

Comment: I think i understood your question, so after you save, you cant see the Image because it is saved in the database like  imagename.jpg, and teh real path is /images/news/imagename.jpg, thats the problem that you are facing? it should be like  <asp:Image ID="Image11" runat="server" ImageUrl=' <%# "Images/news/" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pic").ToString() %>' Height="50px" onerror="this.style.display='none'" />

Comment: @Mr - Thanks, that solved part of the problem. But the path is still stored in the database. I have updated the question so that the code from saving to the database are included. I suppose I should make some adjustments there so it only save the filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the `ImageUrl` attribute in your ItemTemplate (in a GridView or FormView probably?).

```
<EditItemTemplate>
  <asp:UpdatePanel...>
    ...
    <ContentTemplate>
      ..
      <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("pic") %>' />
    </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

So when you update, this value will be bound to the `<asp:Parameter Name="pic" />` in the `SqlDataSource` control. But in the code behind file you set this value to the complete virtual path (because you want the image to be displayed correctly).

```
var imageViewer = (Image)button.Parent.FindControl("Image1");
...
imageViewer.ImageUrl = virtualFilePath;
```

So that is why this complete virtual path is saved to the database. To fix it you must bind the parameter value to a hidden control, and only use eval for the image control:

```
<asp:Hidden ID="ImageFileName" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("pic") %>' />
<asp:Image ... ImageUrl='<%# Eval("pic", "~/images/news/{0}") %>'
```

In your code behind, set the value for the hidden control to the filename:

```
var imageViewer = (Image)button.Parent.FindControl("Image1");
var imageFileName = (Hidden)button.Parent.FindControl("ImageFileName");
...
imageViewer.ImageUrl = virtualFilePath;
imageFileName.ImageUrl = fileName;
```